# mySQL: select * in combination with UNIX_TIMESTAMP

Tags: mysql, select

Right now I'm retrieving data from my database as follows:

`SELECT id, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(cdate) as myunixdate, permalink, title FROM mytable`

But I would like to do it as follows, but it doesn't work.

`SELECT *, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(cdate) FROM mytable`

My question is, how can I combine UNIX_TIMESTAMP without having to specify all the other fields?

Comment: Try using an alias for the table, and qualify the column references, e.g. SELECT UNIX_TIMETAMP(t.cdate), t.* FROM mytable t

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure you didn't try this?

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(cdate), * FROM mytable
```

This won't work as the * has to come first:

```
SELECT *, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(cdate) FROM mytable
```

Aliasing it will make it easier to reference in your code:

```
SELECT *, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(cdate) AS cdate_timestamp FROM mytable
```

Comment: SELECT t.*, UNIX_TIMETAMP(t.cdate) FROM mytable t

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT *, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(cdate) AS my_time_stamp FROM mytable
```

Answer (score 1):

It works for me in MySQL 6,
Are you sure the second query is the one you really try?
What version of mysql do you use?